# Springboot + Oracle6.jar

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to deploy a .war on a tomcat webserver but I'm getting this error

```
2020-01-28 15:29:52.882 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.hibernate.Version : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2020-01-28 15:29:52.882  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2020-01-28 15:29:52.886 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-01-28 15:29:53.133 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-01-28 15:29:53.640 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-28 15:29:53.641 WARN 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-01-28 15:30:24.670 ERROR 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at com.hp.csoem.crs.CrsApplication.main(CrsApplication.java:11) ~[classes!/:1.0.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) ~[crs.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) ~[crs.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[crs.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[crs.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:523) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518) ~[ojdbc-8.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket read timed out, socket connect lapse 30000 ms.  30000 1 true
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket read timed out, socket connect lapse 30000 ms.
```

Comment: probably two options:
- your application is running on server which doesn't "see" your DB
- you have wrong connection string, try to verify it in squirell for example.

Comment: Based on the error message `driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.` I suppose you don't have correctly package the jdbc drive in your war file ....

Comment: Curious - your question says Oracle6 but the error suggests it's using Oracle8? Have you downloaded the oracle driver and added it to your classpath / maven repository?